# Is there a way to output more Matrix fields than one?

Tags: matrix, entry

I'm struggling to get an element criteria model of more matrix fields at once for entry related to tagField.

**Example:**
I have two matrixFields, where I want them in `{% for block in entry.matrixFieldhandle %}` loop.

I could do

```
{% for block in entry.matrixFieldhandle1 %} My stuff {% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% for block in entry.matrixFieldhandle2 %} My stuff {% endfor %}
```

but it's kind of silly to always set element model for each field. Anything simpler?

Couldn't find anything explanatory in documentation or here.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... Wouldn't you just output them back-to-back? Don't your matrix fields contain different block types, and therefore have different requirements for being displayed?

Comment: Question updated. I have the field's structure strictly set to met my needs for site. Matrix field(set according to categories) -> Block type -> Field

Comment: Instead of creating multiple matrix fields and trying to merge them, I would suggest simply creating a new 'block type' within the same matrix with different fields defined. That is the beauty of matrix fields!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but you could try this:

```
{% set allMatrixBlocks = entry.matrixFieldhandle1.find | merge(entry.matrixFieldhandle2.find) %}

{% for block in allMatrixBlocks %} My stuff {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It didn't work, because it isn't array.

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer to include `.find`. That will convert each field into an array of matrix blocks. In some cases, Craft will automatically convert an ElementCriteriaModel into an array if it's being treated as an array... I wasn't sure if this was one of those situations (apparently it isn't).

Comment: It works as it should! :)